# How to hook a logout funtion for specific usr role in wordpress?

Tags: php, wp-login-form, logout

I am using plugin for login/logout(https://wordpress.org/plugins/login-logout-menu/) navigation link to be dynamic. Once user role logged in they will redirect to specific page  and functionality is working fine. For logged out it should redirect to home page for specific role. I have tried using the hooks provided but it is not working. Currently admin and normal user role logged out to the default login redirect link which is in the wordpress.

```
 function redirect_after_logout() {

        $current_user   = wp_get_current_user();
        $role_name      = $current_user->roles[0];

        if($role_name == 'employee'){
            $redirect_url = site_url();
            wp_safe_redirect( $redirect_url );
            exit;
        } 

    }
    add_action( 'wp_logout', 'redirect_after_logout'  );
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`wp_logout`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_logout/) action fires *after* the user is logged out. They no longer have a role.

However, since WordPress 5.5.0, the hook takes one parameter: the ID of the user who is being logged out. So you might be able to accomplish your goal by using that ID instead of `wp_get_current_user()`.

```
function redirect_after_logout( $user_id ) {

    $current_user   = get_user_by( 'id', $user_id );
    if ( empty( $current_user ) || empty( $current_user->roles ) ) {
        return;
    }
    $role_name      = $current_user->roles[0];

    if($role_name == 'employee'){
        $redirect_url = site_url();
        wp_safe_redirect( $redirect_url );
        exit;
    } 

}
add_action( 'wp_logout', 'redirect_after_logout'  );
```

If you're not using *at least* WordPress 5.5.0, this won't work (and you should probably update, too).

### References

- [`wp_logout`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_logout/)
- [`get_user_by()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_by/)

Comment: Is there a reason ` $role_name      = $current_user->roles[0];` would throw the warning `Trying to access array offset on value of type null`?

Comment: Hmm, the code wasn't checking to see if `$current_user->roles` existed; I've added a quick update to the code to (hopefully) fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks. Should it be checking if it exists?

Comment: It's never a bad idea to check a variable to make sure it's what you expect — eg. an `array` and not `false`.